# Connecting to a serial port/COM1 in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, serial

I have an external device (running a small Linux-based OS) that I need to log in to via the Windows 7 command line. The device is connected to COM1 with a USB-to-serial cable. How do I do this without HyperTerminal (which doesn't come w/7)? I know how I'd connect to a remote IP address or similar location via ssh, but I'm not very familiar with Windows & am having a hard time finding info on how to replicate this particular function of HyperTerminal ...

Edit:
All three suggestions (PuTTy, KiTTy, Tera Term) just returned gibberish, suggesting to me that maybe there's something wrong with the device, my cable, or I just need to read up on how serial ports work some more, I don't know (turned out to be a weird connection speed issue). But it's good to know there are alternatives to Hyperterminal (I really wanted Tera Term to work, too - the vintage 1999 brilliant turquoise website and Y2K disclaimer were fun).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Current versions of PuTTY can connect using [a serial port](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-serial).

Answer (score 2):

The PuTTY fork [KiTTy](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/) supports serial comms too and has some nice features that PuTTY lacks.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this fork - looks like it'll work for an unrelated issue I had, too!

Answer (score 1):

**Tera Term** is a good alternative to HyperTerminal - it's old but works fine on W7 - in fact, I was using it this afternoon on W7 (64-bit) to test an old modem on COM1.

http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA002416/teraterm.html

Comment: That website is absolutely incredible.